# Selecting data from database which is from this week except today

Tags: mysql

I need some help with some a simple query. I want to select data from a table where the date is in this week, but I don't want the records where the date is today. So if today is Monday, then I only want the data from Tuesday to Friday.

This was my best attempt.

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: `AND date != NOW()`?

Comment: That will select the date from now but i dont want it to select the date from today i want to select all data from this week without selecting today. Will " AND date != NOW() " this help me?

Comment: guess you will find out very quickly if you try :-)

Comment: what's going with the question; is it solved? There are a few answers below that seem to do the trick @ViPZoMbie1

Comment: Yea i found a solution thank you guys! it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `between` and `subdate`

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `date`
BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) AND SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CURDATE()

> The CURDATE() function returns the current date.
>
> Note: This function returns the current date as a "YYYY-MM-DD" format
>   if used in a string context, and as a YYYYMMDD format if used in a
>   numeric context.

And DATE()

> The DATE() function extracts the date value from a date or datetime
>   expression.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND DATE(date) < CURDATE();
```

This will effectively turn your data into YYYY-MM-DD and compare with today's YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

You can use between here and go one day back from today.

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Be aware that I have used `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` as curdate does only contain the date without time.